Is it more secure if I add another layer of NGINX reversed proxy behind External Load Balancer of GCP
Is it more secure if I add another layer of NGINX reversed proxy behind External Load Balancer of GCP?
Network topology:
  ┌──────────────────────────────────┐         
  │ GCP External Load Balancer(HTTPS)│         
  └──────────┬───────────────────────┘         
             │                          
             ▼                          
  ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐                 
  │ NGINX(DMZ Network, as subnet of VPC)│                 
  └──────────┬──────────────────────────┘                 
             │ Some firewall rules                         
             ▼                          
  ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  
  │ Backend Services(Another Network, another subnet of same VPC)│  
  └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘                                                                                                         

Any response would be appreciated.

As always with open ended questions, "it depends". If you don't have nginx you will get the https requests directly to your backend service, so you will need to protect the backend from direct requests/attacks from the internet.
Adding a proxy in between makes it possible to intercept the traffic, apply rules etc before sending it on to the backend services, which might be good for some use cases, but it also adds a layer of complexity which may or may not impact your definition of "security".
